# Bootstrap put components nav above others

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap for the first time (first time with frontend too), however I already have problems. One is that the `navbar` is always shown over others components.

```
<body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

      <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
          <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
          </div>
      </div>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

In this case for example the `div` `.container .theme-showcase` is under and I can never see it.

What am I missing? Thank you.

[image]

**EDIT:** removing-fixed-top is not a solution, I need the nav always present

Answer (score 0):

`.navbar-fixed-top` will give the navbar `position: fixed` removing it from the flow so other elements will start at the top of the page. If you want a sticky nav, add top padding to `.container.theme-showcase` or if you want the navbar static, then simply remove the `.navbar-fixed-top` class.

Comment: how should I add top padding?

Comment: @AlessioMTX Either inline or separate stylesheet. Do some study http://htmldog.com/guides/css/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because `.navbar-fixed-top` is `position: fixed`, the `nav` element will lay *on top* of the underlying `div`. Be sure to give `.container .theme-showcase` some `padding-top` to show it beneath the navbar.

Comment: where should I add padding?

Comment: In your CSS, search for `.container` or `.theme-showcase` and add the following:

`.theme-showcase {
  padding-top: 100px; /*height of navbar */
}`